# curl code : stop send http request when it reach specific amount?

Tags: linux, bash, web, curl, parallel-processing

```
target=${1:-http://web1.com}
while true # loop forever, until ctrl+c pressed.
do
    for i in $(seq 10) # perfrom the inner command 10 times.
    do
    curl $target > /dev/null & # send out a curl request, the & indicates not to wait for the response.
    done


    wait # after 100 requests are sent out, wait for their processes to finish before the next iteration.

done
```

I want to train my HTTP load balancing by giving multiple HTTP requests in one time. I found this code to help me to send 10 sequence HTTP requests to web1.com at one time. However, I want the code to stop when reaches 15000 requests.

so in total, there will be 1500 times to send HTTP requests.

thank you for helping me

> **update**

I decide to use Hey.
https://serverfault.com/a/1082007/861352

i use this command to run the request
`hey -n 100 -q 2 -c 1 http://web1.com -A`

which:

```
-n: stop the request when it reaches 100 request
-q: give a break for 2 (not request /second but query /second) to avoid flooding requests at once
-c: send the request at once 1 request
http://web1.com = my web
-A = accept header, I have an error when removing -A
```

Comment: Try to replace `while true` with `for _ in $(seq 1500)`

Comment: thanks, man, unfortunately the code still running continuously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works:

```
target=${1:-http://web1.com}
limit=1500

count=0
while true # loop forever, until ctrl+c pressed.
do
    for i in $(seq 10) # perfrom the inner command 10 times.
    do
    count=$(expr $count + 1) # increments +1
    curl -sk $target > /dev/null & # send out a curl request, the & indicates not to wait for the response
    done


    wait # after 100 requests are sent out, wait for their processes to finish before the next iteration.

if [ $count -ge $limit ];then
exit 0
fi
done
```

Comment: Ron thank you, your code is working, however, there is a time the output stop or froze. so I dont know if the code is still wanna run the code or the job is done.

Comment: Your question asks how to stop at a certain number of request/cycles. If the curl takes time to complete, that is completely separate issue.. This code runs until a limit of requests is reached.. which answers the question.

Comment: i mean yout last output code is 
```100   160  100   160    0     0     10      0  0:00:16  0:00:15  0:00:01    42
100   160  100   160    0     0     10      0  0:00:16  0:00:15  0:00:01    42```
 while my previous code is back to ```root#``` prompt, so I knew the job is finished.

Comment: what is this output? My code does not output anything... if this is the output of curl, you can add `-s` as I did in the code..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you're really looking for is a basic command-line stress-test tool.

For instance [siege](https://www.joedog.org/siege-manual/) is particularly simple and easy to use:

```
siege --delay 1 --concurrent 10 --reps 1500 http://web1.com
```

will do pretty much what you're expecting...

[introduction article about siege](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-benchmark-website-with-siege-command-line-tool/)

Comment: thanks, man, it was useful, I succeed in using your suggestion. I figured it out that the siege detects huge requests as buffer overflow. I send huge repetition to 3 websites of mine in a local network. http://web1.com,  http://web1.com/file, http://web1.com/services. I do also make a file and put multiple sites and run them at once. I got ``*** buffer overflow detected ***: siege terminated ``` do you have any idea ?

Comment: It only happens for web1.com/services, I think the problem is not the siege but my web service deployment